# To git clone or to git fetch

Tags: git, github

After some reading and playing with git, I am still not sure in something crucial. I would like to work on the same code from two different computers. I have already created a repository on GitHub and commited the changes from the computer I was working till now. Now I would like to have the code on the other computer. I should again make a directory, make `git init` and then add the remote repository.

Now, should I fork the project if it's only me that work on the project?
Should I clone this project in the other computer or should I just do `git pull` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each new computer that you want a copy of the repository on, you need to `git clone` the repository.

You should *not* do `git init` again on the second computer.  `git init` creates a new project.

I think you will find that you can't do a `git pull` on your second computer until you have done a `git clone` first, on that computer.   After you have done `git clone` on the second computer, you will do `git pull` and `git push` as normal.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` initiates a new repository from a remote one. It is needed only the first time. You don't need to `git init` before, just run it from the place you want it to be, a new directory will be created in it for you:

```
 git clone /path/to/remote/project
```

This will create the `project` directory in the current one, and checkout files of the current `master` branch.

`git fetch` and `git pull` (Google for the difference between both) are then used later to synchronize a working copy from the other one.

In your case, where you don't have a central "bare" repository, don't try to `push` to the other repository, but `fetch` from it.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the last part, I have only one repository on GitHub that I'm working with. Can't I push and pull normally after I clone it to the second computer?

Comment: Sure, if it's on GitHub it's no problem to push to it, since it's a bare one. I thought your both repos were non-bare ones. In which case you can pull (or fetch), but don't push. See [this article](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html). There are workarounds, but I would advise not to use them.